# Fulltext search on partial word (like "prefix%")

Tags: mysql, sql, select, full-text-search, where-clause

To search for a full word in a mysql fts search I can do:

```
select * from pdxa where match(_search ) against ('everywhere')
```

is there a way to just search for the start of a word, such as:

```
select * from pdxa where _search like 'every%'
```

Comment: The wildcard operator for full-text *boolean mode* search is `*` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In boolean mode, you can use `*` as a wildcard:

```
select * from pdxa where match(_search ) against ('every*' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: thanks, why does it need to be `in boolean mode` for this?

Comment: @David542: welcome. That's how [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) describes this feature. Actually if you think about it, how would you define the relevancy of a partial search?